# Intersection of two two-dimensional Arrays on one dimension

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am new to Ruby. I have a two-dimensional Array of the following form (It is probably an array of hash entries (key, value pairs) as argument to a function and not being initialised in the same way I have shown here):

```
a = [[:"49e8cfb", 1],
[:"4b5a73dc", 1],
[:"4c1e65c4", 1],
[:"4cb4c06f", 1],
[:"4cc0ac3c", 5],
[:"4d8ee865", 21]]
```

And I have another similar Array (say `b`). I want to find intersection of the two Arrays based only on the first column (the string values). For example, if

```
b = [[:"49e8cfb", 2],
[:"4b5a73dc", 78],
[:"4c1e65c4", 4],
[:"4cb4c06f", 3],
[:"4cc0ac3c", 52]]
```

Then the intersection should be

```
[:"49e8cfb", :"4b5a73dc", :"4c1e65c4", :"4cb4c06f", :"4cc0ac3c"]
```

Comment: Your `b` was not correct. You didn't end it with `]`. So that error came. Now run it again...

Comment: The array is not being initialised in the way I have shown here. Sorry I provided less information but its a big program. The type of first element is Symbol and its not working with that...

Comment: You mean `[:"49e8cfb", 1]` is actually `{:"49e8cfb" => 1}` ?

Comment: When I am printing the arguments on screen, it is in the way I have written and the type of argument is array.

Comment: May be then you can check the source code first and see what the exact data is, how then you got like `[ [..],[..] ]`.... Without real input example, I can't edit my answer. But don't change the input data you are now having. Rather Edit with new data... I will take a look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below using [`Array#&`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26) :

```
a.map(&:first) & b.map(&:first)
```

- `a.map(&:first)` will you give you an array of all first entry from the inner arays of `a`.
- `b.map(&:first)` will do the same as I just said.
- Then use `&`, on the 2 resultant arrays returned from `a.map(&:first)` and `b.map(&:first)`.

Comment: I am getting this message.........rb:460:in `map':
undefined method `first' for :"425c610":Symbol (NoMethodError)

Comment: @NGInd His code works fine for me. Be sure to call `.map` on the main Array, not on the inner Array. Just use his code with your `a` and `b`, it works here.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers OP's second array was wrong.. which was causing error. I just fixed it. :-)

Comment: Sorry I provided less information but the type of first element is Symbol

Comment: Yes the `,` at the end, I know :) I fixed that too when I ran your code ;)

Comment: It is probably an array of hash entries (key, value pairs)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
a.group_by(&:first).keys & b.group_by(&:first).keys
=> [:"49e8cfb", :"4b5a73dc", :"4c1e65c4", :"4cb4c06f", :"4cc0ac3c"]
```

require 'benchmark'

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { a.group_by(&:first).keys & b.group_by(&:first).keys }
  x.report { a.map(&:first) & b.map(&:first) }
  x.report { a.collect(&:first) & b.collect(&:first) }
end

    user      system      total        real
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   (  0.000029)
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   (  0.000015)
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   (  0.000012)
```

So use `a.collect(&:first) & b.collect(&:first)` as it is the fastest.

Comment: Why you need to create the `Hash`, then fetch keys and then *intersection* ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this

```
Hash[a].keys & Hash[b].keys
#=> [:"49e8cfb", :"4b5a73dc", :"4c1e65c4", :"4cb4c06f", :"4cc0ac3c"]
```

This will convert both objects into a Hash and only return the keys that exist in both hashs. but `collect` is the fastest as @AlokAnand pointed out.